# Coffeescript Array Indexing

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, coffeescript

If I have an array of photos in coffeescript

```
photos = [ly.p1, ly.p2, ly.p3, ly.p4, ly.p5, ly.p6, ly.p7, ly.p8, ly.p9, ly.p10, ly.p11, ly.p12]

for photo, i in photos
    photoMask = new Layer
```

How can I write my for loop so that the resulting `photoMask` objects are outputted as photoMask1, photoMask2, photoMask3 .. photoMask12 ?

---

EDIT: Further elaboration

Maybe the best way to explain this is what I am trying to do in psuedocode:

```
for photo, i in photos
    photoMask[i] = new Layer
    photoMask[i].addSubLayer(photo)
```

So `ly.p1` would have a corresponding `photoMask1`. That way, I can access `photoMask1` separately and independently.

Comment: Why do you want to create 12 variables when an array or object would be easier to work with?

Comment: @muistooshort its the nature of the tool that I am using. Any ideas here?

Comment: Are you sure the tool requires a bunch of variables? That doesn't make sense, what is this tool?

Comment: Hey @muistooshort thanks for the comments. I added some context above if you have any ideas that might help. I appreciate your commentary so far.

Comment: .. And the tool I'm using is a prototyping tool called Framer.js. I am trying to create layers (ex `photoMask1`) to correspond with their parent layer (ex. `ly.p1`) so that I can access `photoMask1` separately and independently. Currently, the `photoMask` objects are created, but they aren't named so I cannot access them later. Any kind of method to do this is really the goal here. Thanks a ton for any ideas.

Comment: Why not store them in parallel arrays? Or an array of two key objects (one key for `ly.pX` and one for the corresponding `Layer`)?

Comment: I guess the problem is that I don't know how to construct an array of `photoMasks` within the array of `photos`.. Apologies if this seems obvious to you

Comment: What's wrong with your pseudocode? That's pretty much working code as-is.

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort. I am getting a "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: photoMask" on the line `photoMask[i] = new Layer`. Do you have any helpful pointers here? I really appreciate any input.

Comment: Declare `photoMask` before the loop or use the comprehension version.

Comment: Thanks @muistooshort. Makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree to the commenters about this being a bit strange, you could use something like this:

```
photos = [ly.p1, ly.p2, ly.p3, ly.p4, ly.p5, ly.p6, ly.p7, ly.p8, ly.p9, ly.p10, ly.p11, ly.p12]

masks = {}

for photo, i in photos
    photoMask = new Layer
    masks["photoMask#{i}"] = photoMask
```

This will create dynamic keynames within the masks object. If you really need them globally (in the browser) you could do the same thing with the `window` object.

But without knowing what exactly you're trying to do, I wouldn't recommend any of the above.

Comment: Thanks that is great to know. I added more context to the question above. I would greatly appreciate it if you have further insight into this problem. Thanks very much for your help so far.